# does not contain a definition for 'GetInt32' and no extension method accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an invoice Window form app, but I face the problem when I put `GetInt32` at the code as below:

```
 private void StoreData()
    {
        int invoiceID;
        int Item_Id;
        int quantity;

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\oo\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Invoice(subtotal,tax,total) values (@subtotal,@tax,@total); select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as InvoiceID;";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtotal", subtotal);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax", totalTaxes);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                        invoiceID = cmd.GetInt("InvoiceID");
                    //invoiceID =(int)cmd.Parameters["@InvoiceID"].Value;
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in OrderItems.Rows)
            {
                using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into InvoiceItem(InvoiceID,ItemID,quantity) values (@InvoiceID,@ItemID,@quantity);";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceID", invoiceID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", Item_Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I do tried the `invoiceID = cmd.SqlDataReader.GetInt32("InvoiceID");` and  `invoiceID = cmd.SqlDataReader.GetInt32("InvoiceID");`, but does not work.

Comment: Look at the signature, it accepts an `int ordinal`, not a `string columnName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetInt32` expects the ordinal position of your column. To specify the column name instead, you can use the [string indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `SqlDataReader`, which accepts the column name:

```
invoiceID = (int)reader["InvoiceID"];
```

This assumes that your `InvoiceID` column is not nullable. If it is, you should use `GetOrdinal` and `IsDBNull` instead.

Comment: but it affect the "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", item.Item_Id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", item.quantity);" Do you have any idea? What wrong with this? I am beginner for C#

Comment: yes, i get the error saying "object does not contain a definition for Item_Id and no extension method 'Item_Id' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)",